# found missing "record stores" in android from j2me

Tags: android

Higuys, i have an application in j2me which uses the method RecordStore.listRecordStores().
i need to implement the same application in android. does anyone know the corresponding method in android???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For persistent storage on an Android device you have the following options:

- Preferences, which store key-value pairs
- Output to files, either stored on the device's internal memory or on the SD Card
- SQLite Databases

You can [read about all these different options here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: thanks  dave, i chose external storage from second option. how will get the availability of a particular external storage device??

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, the only external storage device will be the SD card, there are methods for acessing this but it depends on what version of android you want to support in what methods you are going to use.

You can use this method call to get the DIR to store on the SD card

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()